# my sound doesnt work on ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

i have a hp pavilion s7320n Slimeline pc with onboard audio. how do i get audio to work? i went to youtube to do a test run on audio. i installed the flash player and the video plays but no audio. i also tried to download a mp3 file to test the audio and nothing. what can i do?

thanks

Comment: i figured it out. i had to update my alsa from 1.20 to 1.21 from this page http://monespaceperso.org/blog-en/2009/10/29/upgrade-alsa-1-0-21-on-ubuntu-karmic-koala-9-10/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you have the sound turned on, should be in the top panel, click right on the speaker icon, and choose "Sounds Preferences". Make sure you got the output volume higher as 0% obviously, also make sure you have a working audio device, I have mine on 5.1 surround output, but this might not work for a normal onboard audio card, so make sure you choose "Stereo output".

[image]

If this didn't work there has to be a codec problem. A very easy way to install sound and video codecs if the package ubuntu-restricted-extras.

You install it using this command

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 0):

If it worked on 9.04 but not in 9.10 check that you are booting from the kernel included in 9.10: `vmlinux-2.6.31-14-generic` and not the one from 9.04 `vmlinux-2.6.28-16-generic`. This can happen if you clicked off a dialog asking you to update grub's menu.lst during installation.